DNS resolving - different results
I've inherited a couple of servers, they're in different networks and different sites, yet, I've assumed they all had the same configuration, I couldn't figure out what causes the following behaviour:

nslookup in some servers return the expected machine FQDN, others just return "localhost". They're all DC's, with primary DNS set to the machine IP and secondary to a different DNS server. DC's host both DHCP and DNS server services.
Not sure if related, but I'm also having an issue with netmask priority in DNS, I've set it, disabled round-robin, and still, some machines are resolving names in a different site. Manually setting the order didn't help as sync between them will break it again.
What am I missing? For context, I'm more used to *nix, not MS Windows. Thank you.
UPDATE: looks like ipv6 settings were getting in the way.

Not sure if related, but I'm also having an issue with netmask priority in DNS, I've set it, disabled round-robin, and still, some machines are resolving names in a different site. netmask ordering is rarely used and a bit flaky. Broadly speaking, an AD client can use any DC or DNS server... that's the default and part of the open design. Affinity and preference are usually handled with mnemonics and/or registry settings for controlling which records should or shouldn't be registered.

Also, did you check if there are any local settings in
C:\Windows\ System32\drivers\etc\hosts ?

@GregAskew Thansk Greg, but we use DFS and I need to make sure "myhost" points to the correct site, any other way to do it?

Seems that some servers had IPv6 disabled, others enabled, and others enabled with manual DNS setting to ::1
Setting them all to auto+enabled fixed the issue.
Now, I have a different situation regarding DFS, but will open a new post.
Thank you.
